# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre System::Char y simplemente char cuando se declaran como variables públicas?

Tags: c++, .net

En la declaración de variables:

```
class Estructura
{ 
    public:
         System::Char nombre[80];
}
```

¿Por qué no declarar solamente?:

```
Char nombre[80];
```

Comment: Esto suena más a C#... ¿No te habrás equivocado de lenguaje?

Comment: ¿Qué librerías estás usando? `System::Char` no es C++ estándar.

Comment: Es [C++.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.char(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ah, eso explica que la sintaxis sea C++ pero los tipos sean diferentes.